# Dynamiacally adding an ID to a table row using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jsgrid

I am using jsgrid to create an on the glass datagrid in a web app and now need to add an ID to each row so a row can be selected and a key value passed through to the back end.

The code I'm trying to use id shown below, I have managed to confirm the values are present for each fieldData record(this is the object where the row data is held.)
The function runs a for loop using the variable iRDG2 to cycle through the table rows and URN the keypair that relates to the unique reference number;

```
$('tbody').children()[iRDG2].attr('id', fieldData[iRDG2].URN);
```

Unfortunately the JS engine in browser tells me that Object doesn't support property, possibly as the rows have cells contained.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post your table data here?

Comment: you need JQuery object to use attr
`$($('tbody').children()[iRDG2]).attr('id', fieldData[iRDG2].URN);`

Comment: I am using jQuery. Sorry I didn't make that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your code like the following:

```
$('tbody').children().eq(iRDG2).attr('id', fieldData[iRDG2].URN);
```

But if you change rows with external code you should ensure that it's done on `onRefreshed` callback. Because grid content could be refreshed, so ids will be lost.

Probably better alternative would be to use `rowClass` option to assign unique class to each row, for instance:

```
rowClass: function(item, itemIndex) { return "row-" + item.ID },
```

So you can reference a row by this class: `$(".row-123")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions but I ended up going down a route where the row updated a variable with the value of the first child of the row instead as worked first time